# VirtualBox : Failed to open a session for the virtual machine (for Genymotion)

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have been trying to solve this problem the last two days without success.

I installed Genymotion and VirtualBox, when I try to run a virtual android device (anyone) on Genymotion I get this message:

[image]

when I run the virtual box and try to start the virtual machine from it, I get this error:

[image]

I looked around here but I couldn't find a similar problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of genymotion are you using?

Comment: re-install the extension package, and re-install the driver for the usb-device under windows

Comment: The version of genymotion is  2.5.4

Comment: @FrankelStein which windows version are you using?

Comment: Penta, I reinstalled the virtualBox, with the 5.0.4 version

Comment: check my answer, its the solution as seen from the forums

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

If you think it is a registry entry, you might want to check and delete the following entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe"="DISABLEUSERCALLBACKEXCEPTION"
```

From https://community.oracle.com/thread/3639877

Comment: Oddly, I have no "Layers" folder, under the AppCompatFlags !